# aggregating across a dictionary containing dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

i have the following dictionary which contains dataframes as values, each always having the same number of columns (1) with the same title

```
test = {'A': pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10), index=range(10),columns=['values']),
        'B': pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6), index=range(6),columns=['values']),
        'C': pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(11), index=range(11),columns=['values'])}
```

from this, i would like to create a single dataframe where the index values are the key values of the dictionary (so A,B,C) and the columns are the union of the current index values across all dictionaries (so in this case 0,1,2,3...10). the values of this dataframe would be the corresponding 'values' from the dataframe corresponding to each row, and where blank, NaN

is there a handy way to do this?

Comment: You need `pd.concat`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, use `pd.concat`, `keys`, and `unstack`:

```
pd.concat([test[i] for i in test], keys=test.keys()).unstack(1)['values']
```

Better yet,

```
pd.concat(test).unstack(1)['values']
```

Output:

```
         0         1         2         3         4         5         6   \
A -0.029027 -0.530398 -0.866021  1.331116  0.090178  1.044801 -1.586620   
C  1.320105  1.244250 -0.162734  0.942929 -0.309025 -0.853728  1.606805   
B -1.683822  1.015894 -0.178339 -0.958557 -0.910549 -1.612449       NaN   

         7         8         9         10  
A -1.072210  1.654565 -1.188060       NaN  
C  1.642461 -0.137037 -1.416697 -0.349107  
B       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: this looks good. i think you can do without the list comprehension in the first argument of concat(). in fact, the desired output looks like it is achieved with: pd.concat(test).unstack(1)['values']

Comment: @laszlopanaflex You are so correct.  I hate when I overthink/overlook the simple stuff.

Comment: @laszlopanaflex - Super solution, dont forget upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

dont over complicate things:
just use concat and transpose

```
pd.concat(test, axis=1).T

                0         1         2         3         4         5   \
A values -0.592711  0.266518 -0.774702  0.826701 -2.642054 -0.366401   
B values -0.709410 -0.463603  0.058129 -0.054475 -1.060643  0.081655   
C values  1.384366  0.662186 -1.467564  0.449142 -1.368751  1.629717   
                6         7         8         9         10  
A values  0.431069  0.761245 -1.125767  0.614622       NaN  
B values       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  
C values  0.988287 -1.508384  0.214971 -0.062339 -0.011547
```

if you were dealing with series instead of 1 column DataFrame it would make more sense to begin with...

```
test = {'A': pd.Series(np.random.randn(10), index=range(10)),
        'B': pd.Series(np.random.randn(6), index=range(6)),
        'C': pd.Series(np.random.randn(11), index=range(11))}

pd.concat(test,axis=1).T
         0         1         2         3         4         5         6   \
A -0.174565 -2.015950  0.051496 -0.433199  0.073010 -0.287708 -1.236115   
B  0.935434  0.228623  0.205645 -0.602561  1.860035 -0.921963       NaN   
C  0.944508 -1.296606 -0.079339  0.629038  0.314611 -0.429055 -0.911775   
         7         8         9         10  
A -0.704886 -0.369263 -0.390684       NaN  
B       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  
C  0.815078  0.061458  1.726053 -0.503471
```